# Laravel 4 change route based on current URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have a login form spread across my website on different pages for different situations that are all used in the same POST controller. In the POST controller I always `redirect->back()` so it goes to the previous page the visitor was on. However, now I need it setup differently. I need it to know which page they came from and based on that previous page know which page to redirect the user to.

So basically I need a `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath()` for the previous page. So it can be something like this:

`Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath() == "some/url"` then go to `some/url/2`

If I actually use `getCurrentRoute()` it just shows my POST route and not the route the visitor is coming from.

Comment: `URL::previous();` does that give you what you're looking for?

Comment: Sort of. It will give me the previous page but the absolute link. I need to get just the route page. So URL::previous() gives me localhost/blah/blah. I just need it to show blah/blah.

Comment: then parse the link with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function and extract what you need

Comment: Wow, safe to say I have never knew of that function. Usually I would just explode() it. Thanks a lot!